# Is there some u-boot specific device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, boot-loader, u-boot

I was reading [this thread](https://community.toradex.com/t/verdin-imx8m-plus-gpio-states-during-reset/16494/10) and someone mentioned a "u-boot device tree", which seems to be different than a "kernel device tree".  They said:

> I would make same change to uboot device tree same as you mentioned
> here for kernel device trees for that GPIO line.

Is there some device tree that tells u-boot about hardware other than the one it loads for the kernel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711327/why-device-tree-structure-dts-file-is-needed-both-in-bootloader-and-kernel-sou